# MDX Calculate the sum of distinct values

Tags: distinct, mdx, pentaho

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a calculated member to obtain the sum of distinct values for a fact. I will try to explain it with the following example:

I have a fact where the primary key is related with two dimensions (one to many cardinality). The fact contains a measure and its value is the same for all members of each distinct combination of FACT_ID and DIM_1_ID. For the total, I don't want to consider multiple times the same values. So, with the following values **the total should be 450 and not 850** (default Mondrian behavior).

```
    | FACT_ID | DIM_1_ID | DIM_2_ID | MEASURE |
    |---------|----------|----------|---------|
    | 1       | A        | D        | 100     |
    | 1       | A        | E        | 100     |
    | 1       | B        | F        | 50      |
    | 2       | A        | D        | 300     |
    | 2       | A        | E        | 300     |
    |---------|----------|----------|---------|
                              TOTAL | 450     |
```

Is it possible? How can it be done with Mondrian?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE - Current status**

As described in one of the comments bellow, base on @whytheq's answer, I managed to calculate the right value for the total, using the following MDX formula for the measure:

```
Sum( 
    Order(
        [dActivity.hActivity].[lActivity].MEMBERS*[dFacility.hFacility].[lFacilit‌​y].MEMBERS, 
        [dActivity.hActivity].[lActivity].currentmember.name
    ) as [m_set] , 
    iif( 
        [m_set].currentordinal = 0 
        OR 
        not(
            [m_set]
            .item([m_set].currentordinal)
            .item(0).NAME 
            = 
            [m_set]
            .item([m_set].currentordinal-1)
            .item(0).NAME
        ) , 
        [Measures].[mBudget] 
        , 
        0 
    ) 
)
```

However, this expression is using the complete set for every single row, so the result overrides the measure real value for the different fact rows.

```
    | FACT_ID | DIM_1_ID | DIM_2_ID | MEASURE |
    |---------|----------|----------|---------|
    | 1       | A        | D        | 450     |
    | 1       | A        | E        | 450     |
    | 1       | B        | F        | 450     |
    | 2       | A        | D        | 450     |
    | 2       | A        | E        | 450     |
    |---------|----------|----------|---------|
                              TOTAL | 450     |
```

Comment: what's the use of DIM_2_ID?

Comment: For the question I tried to simplify the problem as much as I could. In the real problem FACT_ID represents a work to be done (it is also another dimension), DIM_1_ID a period in time and DIM_2_ID the location. The measure is the budget for per work per period.

Answer (score 1):

Great question - really tricky to do in MDX.

If we do the following then there are 158 rows returned - a handful have duplicate values for `[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]`:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      [Product].[Product].[Product]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,bdesc
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This only counts them if the member above is different for the respective measure:

```
WITH 
  SET [x] AS 
    Order
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Product].[Product].[Product]
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,bdesc
    ) 
  SET [FILTERED] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [x]
     ,
        (
          [x].Item(
          [x].CurrentOrdinal - 1)
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
      <> 
        (
          [x].Item(
          [x].CurrentOrdinal)
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[distCount] AS 
    Count([FILTERED]) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[distCount] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Maybe try adding the EXISTING keyword into your calculatio:

```
Sum
(
  Order
  (
     EXISTING   //<<<
      [dActivity.hActivity].[lActivity].MEMBERS
    * 
      [dFacility.hFacility].[lFacilit‌​y].MEMBERS
   ,[dActivity.hActivity].[lActivity].CurrentMember.Name
  ) AS [m_set]
 ,IIF
  (
      [m_set].CurrentOrdinal = 0
    OR 
      (NOT 
          [m_set].Item(
          [m_set].CurrentOrdinal).Item(0).Name
        = 
          [m_set].Item(
          [m_set].CurrentOrdinal - 1).Item(0).Name)
   ,[Measures].[mBudget]
   ,0
  )
)
```

Comment: Following your example I've created the following one that shows the right total value:
`Sum(
 Order([dActivity.hActivity].[lActivity].MEMBERS*[dFacility.hFacility].[lFacility].MEMBERS, [dActivity.hActivity].[lActivity].currentmember.name) as [m_set]
 , iif(
  [m_set].currentordinal = 0 OR not([m_set].item([m_set].currentordinal).item(0).NAME = [m_set].item([m_set].currentordinal-1).item(0).NAME)
  , [Measures].[mBudget]
  , 0
 )
)`
However, now the total value is shown for every row, not just for the total. Is there any way to enforce the use of this expression only for the totals?

Comment: @r0dx1 Ilike you addition of `[m_set].CurrentOrdinal = 0
    OR` ....last night I could not remember that bit

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case I'm using Pentaho and EXISTING is not supported. Apparently there is no workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to obtain the average over the set. The code is a bit complex.

```
WITH SET SomeSet AS 
{
        Fact.FactID.FactID.MEMBERS
        *
        Fact.DimID1.DimID1.MEMBERS
        *
        Fact.DimID2.DimID2.MEMBERS
}
MEMBER Measures.AvgVal AS
AVG
    (
     {Fact.FactID.CURRENTMEMBER}
     *
     {Fact.DimID1.CURRENTMEMBER}
     *
     NonEmpty
        (
         Fact.DimID2.DimID2.MEMBERS,
         {{Fact.FactID.CURRENTMEMBER} * 
         {Fact.DimID1.CURRENTMEMBER}} * 
         [Measures].[TheMeasure]
        )
     ,
     [Measures].[TheMeasure]
    )


SELECT NON EMPTY SomeSet ON 1,
NON EMPTY {
           [Measures].[TheMeasure], 
           Measures.AvgVal
          } on 0
from [YourCube]
```

What I am doing is, for the current `FactID`- `DimID1` combination on the axis, I am getting the list of all possible `DimID2`s and then, over the internally generated non-empty tuples of `FactID-DimID1-DimID2`, deriving the average value of the measure `TheMeasure`

So, for example (100+100)/2 = 100 value would be displayed for the combination of `FactID = 1` and `DimID1 = A`

Comment: (not sure if you've misread the question matey) the OP is in connection with a distinct count of values....so if for Product "bike" there is four Internet sale amounts {55,123,123,400} then the questioner wants an answer of 3 - a distinct count of these numbers.

Comment: True. But he says - the fact contains a measure and its value is same for all members for each distinct combination of those two columns. In such a scenario, mathematically sum over distinct is same as average over all. Won't you agree?

Comment: Also, he wants the sum over distinct combination(doesn't want to count more than once), not the count.

Comment: My interpretation was that the measure is the same, and getting repeated,  because he has implemented my idea but the new measure is not context aware - hence I suggested adding EXISTING: now he needs a workaround as this isn't supported in Mondrian. See if you can adapt my answer so it becomes context aware without EXISTING?

Comment: @SouravA I will try it tomorrow, I cannot do it now. In principal I think you are right and that could work. In the end what I'm interested on is on the aggregation of the measure values, not in the count of distinct elements.

Comment: Yes, I later realized you are interested in the aggregation. But the "count" or the "sum"?